# EMFile: too many open files, watch - building Release react native iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, apple-m1

I wrote my React Native app using Expo, and then ejected it using `expo eject`. I am now trying to build release versions of the app. It works fine for Android, and also for debug builds for iOS, but when I try to build for release on Xcode I get the following error:

```
Error: EMFILE: too many open files, watch
    at FSEvent.FSWatcher._handle.onchange (internal/fs/watchers.js:178:28)
Emitted 'error' event on NodeWatcher instance at:
    at NodeWatcher.checkedEmitError (/node_modules/sane/src/node_watcher.js:143:12)
    at FSWatcher.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at FSEvent.FSWatcher._handle.onchange (internal/fs/watchers.js:184:12) {
  errno: -24,
  syscall: 'watch',
  code: 'EMFILE',
  filename: null
}
```

I have seen a few other people with similar errors, and tried the following steps with no luck:

- tried different versions of node
- updated watchman
- reinstalled homebrew
- closed all windows/application apart from Xcode

I have a feeling the error is to do with the M1 chip, but am really struggling to find a solution, so any help is appreciated.

**Device** - Mac mini (M1, 2020), running macOS Monterey 12.0.1

**Node Version** - 17.0.1

**React Native Version** - ~0.63.4

I used [this](https://medium.com/@davidjasonharding/developing-a-react-native-app-on-an-m1-mac-without-rosetta-29fcc7314d70) article for setting up the environment

Let me know if you require anymore information/snippets

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue earlier this year. It was indeed because of the M1 chip and XCode not building properly when watchman was installed without Rosetta.

I was building on an M1 Mac using XCode 12.5 and had to:

- Install watchman on using an x86_64 instance of homebrew
- Run the metro server in a Rosetta terminal
- Run XCode **without** Rosetta

If this is the first time you're installing a package using the x86_64 instance of homebrew remember to add it to your PATH.

Comment: Thank you, will give this a try. Is the x86_64 homebrew the M1 one? If not, do you have any links to how to install this. And then when you say run metro server, do you just mean `npm start` in a terminal while the app is building?

Comment: The x86_64 instance of homebrew is one installed using a Rosetta terminal (not the default ARM one that M1 macs use).

Yes its a simple `npm start` in the terminal but run it before building the app in xcode.

Answer (score 0):

We can solve this issue by the following commands

```
brew install watchman

sudo launchctl limit maxfiles 16384 16384 && ulimit -n 16384
```